# SVG tile interactivity with vue leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, mapping, svg, vue.js

I am not being able to extract or interact with the svg tiles data on mouse hover/click using leaflet.

I have a tile server that serves svg tiles eg:[https://sometileserver.com/roads/{z}/{x}/{y}.svg](https://sometileserver.com/roads/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.svg), the svgs returned in this have some attributes embedded in each path drawn on them. I am using leaflet in my vue app to show the tiles.
example of how I am loading my tiles:

```
const tileUrl = "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";
const tiles = L.tileLayer(tileUrl, {
        attribution
      });
      var myMap = L.map("mapContainer", {
        layers: tiles
      }).setView([0,0], 12);

const roads = L.tileLayer('https://sometileserver.com/roads/{z}/{x}/{y}.svg', {
        attribution
      }).addTo(map)
```

At this point leaflet shows the svg tiles on top of the OSM base map which is great. however these svg tiles has many roads drawn on them and each such road/path has some attributes about it embedded into.
an example of one such svg tile:

```
<ns0:svg xmlns:ns0="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="256pt" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 256 256" width="256pt">
<ns0:g id="surface4396">
<ns0:path d="M 254 13 L 252 13 " road_status="[1.04,4.09]" road_id="abc" road_name="unknown" style="fill:none;stroke-width:3.0;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke:rgb(0%,100%,0%);stroke-opacity:1;stroke-miterlimit:10;" />
</ns0:g>
</ns0:svg>
```

My goal is to show those attributes/values(eg:road_id,road_name) when I hover over each road/path drawn on this tile.

Comment: I'm afraid you took the wrong path to achieve your goal. The only way to achieve this in vanilla Leaflet is through GeoJSON vector layers. There are of course various Leaflet plugins that offer this functionality, for example Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile https://github.com/SpatialServer/Leaflet.MapboxVectorTile or Leaflet.VectorGrid https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid, but in this case you have to convert your data to appropriate format for the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it was really helpful. I went ahead with the GeoJSON vector layers.